# Optimize SQL query using `COUNT`

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, query-optimization

I have the SQL query (I am using MariaDB/MySQL) below which works fine. But I am wondering if I can simplify/optimize it. The difficulty I am facing is because of `COUNT` with `INNER JOIN`. Do I really need the subquery `IN` or you think there is a way I can eliminate it?

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM aaa a 
INNER JOIN bbb b ON a.field1 = b.field1 
WHERE a.yyy = 'yyy' AND b.zzz = 'zzz' 
AND a.field1 IN (
    SELECT field1 
    FROM bbb 
    WHERE xxx = 'x' 
    GROUP BY field1 
    HAVING COUNT(field1) <= 5
)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please post table description, explain plan

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We need row counts because that can affect query planning. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com.

Comment: Also, we need to see an actual query, not a paraphrased version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like Barmar's answer, but because of the filtering on `b`, I suggest a small(?) change.  (I rearrange the tables primarily to follow the Optimizer's likely order.)

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*
FROM  (
    SELECT field1 
    FROM bbb 
    WHERE xxx = 'x' 
    GROUP BY field1 
    HAVING COUNT(*) <= 5
) AS bc
INNER JOIN bbb AS b ON b.field1 = bc.field1 
INNER JOIN aaa AS a ON a.field1 = bc.field1
WHERE b.zzz = 'zzz' 
  AND a.yyy = 'yyy'
```

Plus these indexes:

```
    bbb:  INDEX(xxx, field1)  -- this order
    b:    INDEX(field1, zzz)  -- either order
    a:    INDEX(field1, yyy)  -- either order
```

The first two composite indexes will be "covering".

The main change from Barmar's answer was to leave `a.*` for last.

If you want to discuss this Question further, it may be useful to provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Your query may be as good as possible, but you can also try joining with the subquery instead of using `IN`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*
FROM aaa AS a
INNER JOIN bbb b ON a.field1 = b.field1 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT field1 
    FROM bbb 
    WHERE xxx = 'x' 
    GROUP BY field1 
    HAVING COUNT(*) <= 5
) AS bc ON a.field1 = bc.field1
WHERE a.yyy = 'yyy' AND b.zzz = 'zzz'
```

Comment: I am really sorry my friend, I forgot to add `AND b.zzz = 'zzz' ` to my query! I really need `bbb`! I edited my question ok?